# Find the distribution function for Y for the following density function

Tags: probability

I am to find the distribution function for Y given the following density function
$$f(y)=\begin{cases}
y,\quad 0<y<1\\
2-y, \quad 1 \leq y < 2\\
0, \quad\text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases}$$

So since $f(y)$ is given by $\frac{dF(y)}{dy}$, then $F(y)$ should be given by the integral of $f(y)$. So by integrating I get the following:

$$F(y) = \begin{cases}
0, \quad y\leq0 \\
\frac12 y^2,\quad 0<y<1\\
2y-\frac12 y^2, \quad 1 \leq y < 2\\
1, \quad\text{elsewhere}\\
\end{cases}$$

But to be a distribution function $F(y)$ must be continuous for $-\infty < y < \infty$, but my function is not continuous at $y=2$.

Can someone help me get a continuous distribution function? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us compute $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy$ the distribution function:
If $x<0$ then clearly $F(x)=0$.

If $0<x<1$ then
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy = \int_{0}^x f(y)dy = \int_0^x ydy = \frac{x^2}{2}.$$

If $1<x<2$ then
$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(y) dy = \int_0^1 f(y)dy+ \int_1^x (2-y)dy = F(1)+ \bigg(2y - \frac{y^2}{2}\bigg|_{y=1}^{y=x} = \frac{1}{2} + 2x-\frac{x^2}{2} - 2+\frac{1}{2} = 2x-\frac{x^2}{2}-1$$
Remember to subtract the last value here, because you want to compute the accumulated area.

Finally, if $x>2$ then $F(x)=1$. Altogether

$$
F(x)=
\begin{cases} 0, \mbox{ if } x<0 \\
\frac{x^2}{2} \mbox{ if } 0<x<1\\
2x-\frac{x^2}{2}-1 \mbox{ if } 1<x<2\\
1 \mbox{ if } x>2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: So my limits of integration should always start as $-\infty$ to $x$, correct?

Comment: In doing so, it is easier for me to see that I should include the area from 0 to 1, when $1 \leq y < 2$. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Exactly! Very good. No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

For $y\in[1,2]$ $F(y)=F(1)+\int_{1}^y 2-t \, dt=\frac{1}{2}+2(y-1)-\frac{1}{2}(y^2-1)=-\frac{1}{2}y^2+2y-1$